# Order of table in JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join

In which order tables are accessed in the joining of tables in sql server ?

Can we force some specified order ?

Comment: You can change the order with the order by clause, even with a JOIN .

Comment: @aleroot ORDER BY changes the order of the results, not the order that the original tables are are accessed.

Comment: it depends on the relation in between tables and requirement

Comment: @Barmar You can join two subqueries with order by clause ...

Comment: @aleroot That still just orders the result of the join. It doesn't control how the database engine optimizes the query.

Comment: @Barmar yes, but are you sure that the OP is asking for what you intended ? :-)

Comment: I'm pretty sure he's asking about query optimization, not order of results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use the `FORCE ORDER` [query hint](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx) e.g.:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    C
        INNER JOIN B
            ON B.BID = C.BID
        INNER JOIN A
            ON A.AID = B.AID
OPTION (FORCE ORDER);
```

This ensures that the join order indicated by the query syntax is preserved during query optimization. In the below two execution plans the top plan does not have the query hint where as the bottom one does:

[image]

You can see that in the first the optimiser applies the order it thinks best (A then B then C) whereas in the second the original order is maintained (C then B then A). As a general rule I would say unless you understand the optimiser well enough to know why the optimiser is picking a certain plan, and why another plan would be more efficient, and why the optimiser has not picked this better plan then I would stay away from forcing execution plans by using hints, the optimiser usually knows best, and where it doesn't it is more likely to be stale statistics or fragmented indexes etc, rather than something that should be fixed by forcing an execution plan.

The schema and queries above are on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b1170/1).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question properly you may find CTE's or temp tables are a good way to manage complex join scenarios'.

I find them useful to "pre-filter" & control data from joined tables & make queries easier to understand.

Though if you could explain WHY you want to control join order people may be able to help a bit more.

Comment: CTEs will not guarantee anything, in [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b1170/4) even though I have moved tables B and C to a CTE and applied a filter, with no hints SQL-Server still begins with a table scan on A, before joining to B and then to C